# Snipcart add item via JS API

Tags: snipcart

I'm building a very small e-commerce website for selling customizable jewels, so I have a graphical configurator that lets you design the jewel and then you can add it to the cart. The product should have a custom field in JSON format that contains the item configuration. I see that Snipcart has `data-item-custom{x}` fields, but is populated only with dropdowns... is not suitable for me.

Do you think I can handle this situation with Snipcart? Can I simply update via JS the HTML `data-item-` fields content? Or add the item to the cart via JS?

```
addToCart({
 name: 'Bracelet 1',
 customField1: 'JSON HERE'
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [Javascript API](https://docs.snipcart.com/javascript-api-reference/public-api) available for Snipcart.

It does allow to add product dynamically, however, the syntax for custom fields is slightly different. [The example from the doc](https://docs.snipcart.com/javascript-api-reference/public-api#add) for `Snipcart.api.items.add` show how to use custom fields (removed unused fields for brevity):

```
Snipcart.api.items.add({
    "id": "SMARTPHONE",
    "name": "Smartphone",
    "url": "/",
    "price": "399.00",
    "customFields": [{
        "name": "Memory size",
        "options": "16GB|32GB[+50.00]",
        "value": "32GB"
    }]
});
```

So instead of the flattened version with `customFieldX`, you can pass an array to `customFields`. The dropdown format is only used if you pass an `options`. For your use case this would become:

```
Snipcart.api.items.add({
    "id": "SMARTPHONE",
    "name": "Smartphone",
    "url": "/",
    "price": "399.00",
    "customFields": [{
        "name": "configuration",
        "value": "{\"option1\":\"value1\"}" //...
    }]
});
```

However, custom fields are shown to the customer which would not be ideal to show them the raw json data. To pass hidden data you can instead use `metadata` which already expect a JSON object:

```
Snipcart.api.items.add({
    "id": "SMARTPHONE",
    "name": "Smartphone",
    "url": "/",
    "price": "399.00",
    "customFields": [{
    "metadata": {
        "configuration": "configuration data"
    }
});
```